# 'Profile Card Value' is empty

Tags: experience-analytics, personalization, experience-profile

In my Sitecore installation, under '/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Profiles/' i created a profile 'Movies' and profile keys under it corresponding to Action, Comedy and Horror.

Subsequently, i created Profile card and Personas.

The problem i am facing is, the field corresponding to 'Profile Card Value' is empty, as can be seen in the snapshot.

[image]

Even if I enable raw values, there is nothing there. Same can be seen in this image.

[image]
Sitecore version: Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170407).

I have tested the MongoDB connection and is working fine.

There are warnings in the log files log.txt: `Could not find type in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.Personalization.ProfileCardValue`

There are no entries in FXM.log

My issue is same as mentioned [here](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/9/t/3998#pi214filter=all&pi214scroll=false)

Comment: Any errors in the log? That field is a iFrame field. So you should be able to inspect the field and find the iframe url. Something like https://test.mysite.org/sitecore/shell/Applications/Analytics/Personalization/FieldTypes/ProfileCardForm.aspx?hdl=0AA0D52AECE24103B22BBDBF4FD6BBA4

Comment: @ChrisAuer: There are no error or warning in the console.

Comment: How about Sitecore log?

Comment: @ChrisAuer: I have updated the log: Could not find type in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.Personalization.ProfileCardValue

Comment: Do you have the dll `Sitecore.Marketing.Client.dll` in the bin folder?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya: Yes, i have this dll inside the bin.

Comment: @JustDoIt can you please check the raw value of the field.

Comment: @AshishBansal Thanks for suggesting but sorry nothing was there. You can see the same in the screenshot I have updated with.

Comment: @ChrisAuer The iFrame block is not coming. I have checked the aspx page and it is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by accessing the core database and changing the Assembly Field on item /sitecore/system/Field types/Analytics/Profile Card Value from:

Sitecore.Client

to

Sitecore.Marketing.Client

My theory is This must not have applied through our upgrade process from

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a minimum and maximum value for the Profile Keys? The value for the Profile Cards is determined by the min and max values of the keys. 
[image: Profile key showing fields]